# Sender of static EventHandler event

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have class with static `EventHandler` event:

```
public static event EventHandler MyEvent;

static void RaiseEvent()
{
    EventHandler p = MyEvent;

    if (p != null)
    {
        p(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Since I don't have any `this` object which can be used as event sender, I raise this event with `sender = null`. Is it OK to have this parameter set to null, according to .NET programming guidelines? If not, what object can I use as a sender?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Event Design**

> On static events, the *sender* parameter should be null

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229011(v=vs.100)